# Selenium chromedriver not able to download file on virtual machine but downloading on local in headless mode using google-chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, virtual-machine

I am download a file on download button click in default download folder using code below.

```
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": file_download_folder_path,
             "download.prompt_for_download": False,
             "download.directory_upgrade": True,
             "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
             "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
             "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}

   chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

It is working on local in both headless and non headless mode. But when I tried on virtual machine linux ubuntu 20.04 it can't download. Its clicking on download button but file is not getting downloaded.

I checked chromedriver version and google-chrome version are same and latest on virtual machine.

```
# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 120.0.6099.129 

# chromedriver --version
2024/01/01 23:55:13.650613 cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: write unix @->/run/user/1001/bus: write: broken pipe
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.71 (9729082fe6174c0a371fc66501f5efc5d69d3d2b-refs/branch-heads/6099_56@{#13})
```

Script is running in `/opt` directory as root and the download folder is in the /opt directory sub-directory. The file is running as root so it has the necessary permission to write to a given path inside /opt directory. It doesn't print any error as well after clicking on the download button.

Can anyone help me out here? I am new to selenium. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different approaches following approach working seemlessly both in non headless and headless model including from scheduled cronjobs in crontab file.

```
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

    #service = Service(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    # service = Service()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```

So basically, installing ChromeDriver on the script run works like a charm. The same version installed manually created the issue.